# Is Porphyrin Planar?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, coordination-compounds, structural-biology, ligand-field-theory

I have been looking at this diagram from quite some time, I know the 18 pi electron cycle that forms porphin(e) is definitely planar but what about the whole molecule?... The Nitrogen's act as a polydentate ligand with a metal complex so that may be a reason that the whole molecule may not be planar..
Can someone elaborate?

[image: Porphyrin1]
[image: Porphyrin2]
[image: Porphyrin4]

Comment: Our respected member @porphyrin definitely is not planar.  But I guess he would know for sure for the compound. I do not see any reason why it should not be. AFAIK, the H-N are not neighbors, but are placed across the hole.

Comment: only 18 electrons are in the same plane, the rest are not, hence prophyrin is not planar. am i correct? @Poutnik

Comment: I do not think so. Those other ones are just not part of the conjugated ring. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyrin#/media/File:Porphin-18e.png  But the H in H-N may make it nonplanar.

Comment: Porhyrins readily undergo distortions, and speaking of porphyrin metal complexes, they are as planar as metal centers allow them to be.